# Windows 7 display profiles shortcuts for switching monitor setups

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, resolution

I have 3 monitors attached to my 8800GTS, which can only use 2 at a time. I use 3 different setups:

- single screen (1)
- dual screen (1+2)
- single screen + TV out (1+3)

having to click screen resolution and select different screens etc is a bit of a pain, and to get round this I used to have an autohotkey script that opened up the NVIDIA control panel and select a different profile. However in W7, for some reason everytime I select a new profile it seems to mess up all the settings/not work at all.

I was wondering - does windows7 have any built in commands for selecting monitor 1+2, or 1+3 and just 1?

I'd love to have 3 shortcuts on my start menu like I used to!

Comment: I have a similar problem, but using an ATI card. This question is somewhat old, I wonder if you've resolved it yet? Neither posted answer works for me.

Comment: Sorry but no one really offered a working solution that didn't involve paying for software. I suggest you try using autohotkey, best of luck, and please let me know if you find a better solution!

Comment: Are you SURE Win+P doesn't work for you? That was my assumption at first, but I realized if I re-arranged which ports each of my 3 displays was plugged into I could get the exact setup your describing. Computer only = Monitor 1, Extend = Monitor 1 + Monitor 2, Projector Only = Monitor 3 + Monitor 2.

Answer (score 17):

Press Win + P and you get the following super easy way to switch your monitor setup:

[image]

Comment: This doesn't really work for me, as it is only useful if you have 2 screens - I have 3, and sadly it doesn't give any other options

Comment: I was about to downvote this, but after reading Justin Buser's comment I noticted it actually works with 3 screens, too. Now I use Duplicate to watch something on TV and switch to Projector only to extend the screen to my 2nd monitor.

Comment: @falter I realize this is an old thread, but I just found this thread and this popup selection *does* work with 3 screens. I use 3 displays; 1=Primary monitor, 2=Second monitor, 3=Projector.  "Computer only" shows on 1 only.  "Duplicate" shows on 1 and 3.  "Extend" shows on 1 and 2.  "Projector only" shows on 3 only.  Screen resolutions change appropriately between configurations.  This is a great time saver for me.  I am on Win 7 Pro SP1.

Comment: It also makes all your windows no longer maximized, even if they were and are on the same monitor. This is extremely annoying.

Answer (score 11):

I had downloaded Ultramon trial for this exact thing but found I only wanted this specific function for now. So I found this program on sourceforge called [MonitorSwitcher](http://sourceforge.net/projects/monitorswitcher/).

Comment: I'm scared to download anything from sourceforge now. https://notepad-plus-plus.org/news/notepad-plus-plus-leaves-sf.html http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2015/05/sourceforge-grabs-gimp-for-windows-account-wraps-installer-in-bundle-pushing-adware/ http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2015/06/black-mirror-sourceforge-has-now-siezed-nmap-audit-tool-project/ https://blog.l0cal.com/2015/06/02/what-happened-to-sourceforge/

Comment: MonitorSwitcher is a good idea. At first I'd thought the hotkey function doesn't work, but I've found out that the software should be restarted, and now it works perfectly.

Comment: MonitorSwitcher is exactly what I was looking for to quickly disconnect one monitor when I switch it to a different input.

Answer (score 4):

You can define several profiles with **[UltraMon](http://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/overview/)**.

[image]

It supports [scripting](http://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/tour/scripting.asp) and also hotkeys for many features, including applying the profiles:

> **Hotkeys**
>   Various hotkeys are available:
>
> - Move window to next/previous or primary monitor
> - Maximize window to monitor or desktop
> - Center mouse on primary monitor
> - Move mouse to next/previous monitor
> - Disable or enable secondary monitors
> - Launch screen saver
> - Run application or script
> - Launch UltraMon shortcut
> - ***Apply display profile***
> - Lock mouse to active window or primary monitor

Comment: At least for me, on an ATI card with Windows 7, I can't enable my third monitor using Ultramon. It only shows the first two displays in its configuration box.

Comment: And in Windows 8 Ultramon can't mirror 2 monitors and extend a third.

Comment: At least according to their website: "UltraMon provides a custom Display Settings applet with support for configuring more than 10 monitors." I Don't know the details of how that works or what the limitations are.